# Changing Firestore collection path from swiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui-list

I have an array pulled from a Firestore collection and displayed in a swiftUI list. However, I want to pull documents from different collections if the user selects to view them with buttons. For example:

Button 1 → listen too and load from collectionA

Button 2 → listen too and load from collectionB

I would like to load and pass the collection name locally but when I do, the list doesn't update; it just shows no data. (Right now, I update a variable on Firestore as shown below and listen for updates to change the collection path this is not ideal... but does work)

After a few seconds I can print out the new array with the user's new collection selection, but the list view doesn't populate with the data.

Here is some relevant code:

```
struct PostStruct: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var Title: String
    var Content: String
}


@Published var arrayToPopulateList: [PostStruct] = []


func getDataForList() {
    if uniqueUserUID != "" {
        
        //this is the only work around I found → pulling the selected collection from firestore is the only way I can get the swiftUI list to update when the user picks a new collection to view
        store.collection(uniqueUserUID).document("selection")
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnap, error) in
                if let selection = querySnap?.data()?["selected"] {
                    //accesses the collection with path that user picks (ex from buttons that yield different content)
                    self.store.collection(selection as! String)
                        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in

                            if let error = error {
                                print("Error getting postArray: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                return
                            }
                            self.arrayToPopulateList = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap { document in
                                try? document.data(as: PostStruct.self)
                            } ?? []
                            
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

To display the loaded array I'm using a List in swiftUI.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Nice explanation. Can you add a couple relevant snippets of code. Especially the properties that populates your list.

Comment: @SergioBost thanks for the feedback - I updated the post with the relevant struct and get from Firestore function